# Segmentation fault in C++ program using getline and string function

Tags: c++, string

I have written a sample program in C++ and it is crashing. I don't know why this is crashing. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Below is the sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


string foo(string b)
{
  cout << b << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  string fileName = argv[1];

  ifstream ifile(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);

  string line;

  while(getline(ifile , line))
    cout << line << endl;

  ifile.close();

  foo("q");

  return 0;
}
```

I am passing 1.txt as an argument which contains the following contents:

```
a
b
c
```

The output I am getting is:

```
a
b
c
q
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: I used it but not getting any information from it.

Comment: `foo` is  declared to return a string but there is no return.

Comment: Stop ignoring the compiler warnings. They are the first line of defense against simple logic errors.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared `foo()` as returning a `string` object, but there is no `return` statement in `foo()`, so the return value is indeterminate, and the code has **undefined behavior** when the compiler tries to manage the returned `string`.

If you are not going to `return` anything then you need to declare the return value as `void` instead:

```
void foo(string b)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
void foo(string b)
{
  cout << b << endl;
return;
}
```

Comment: could atleast share *why* should it be done this way.